# What is the correct way to prevent Google Translate and other tools from translating an element?

Tags: html

I'm aware of a HTML5 attribute to prevent translation of an element:

```
<span translate="no">Don’t Translate Me</span>
```

But it doesn't work with Google Translate. The following works with Google Translate:

```
<span class="notranslate">Don’t Translate Me</span>
```

Is the HTML translate attribute useless ? Should I use both ?

```
<span class="notranslate" translate="no">Don’t Translate Me</span>
```

Comment: Is the difference between the two chars `”` and `"` relevant? Because XML only accepts `'` and `"` as delimiters for attribute values.

Comment: @zx485, Thank you for pointing this out, there was a typo error in the question.